# Display Data from Google Sheet into Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I am creating a Quiz.
What I did first is to create data in google sheet and here it is

[Link of Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/fireflyelectric.com/spreadsheets/d/1WF2iQSlPXHRco9YhHcN26AdVNOeu6eOVXbDXTHCkFnU/edit?usp=sharing)

as you can see there I have 2 sheet and that is Questions and Answers

My Question is how can i display the Question and Answers in there respective position in Google Forms i am linking them by Question ID

TYSM

Comment: Check the [Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) as it demonstrates connecting Google Sheets to Google Form, which is the first step in your project.

Then there's the [HOW TO CREATE AN ENTIRE GOOGLE FORM FROM SCRATCH FROM A GOOGLE SPREADSHEET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXUsW6VRQak) video tutorial, which may offer additional insight.

Comment: Hello Sir Good Morning, Based on what you gave. It does help but it has an error when adding an Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comments above will help you. This is also code (with help from here) which copies a multiple-choice question from one quiz to another.

If you combine this code with the stuff referred to in the comments about reading stuff from a sheet then you should be ok.

I see that you mention a problem copying images.  I'm stuck at that point too.

```
function copyMultipleChoiceItem(item1, item2) {
//  copies MC question item1 to item2 - tested PDW 17/05/20
//  copy of feedback now working - tested PDW 17/05/30
//
    var item1MC = item1.asMultipleChoiceItem();
//  basic question items
    item2.setTitle(item1.getTitle());
    item2.setHelpText(item1.getHelpText());
    item2.setPoints(item1MC.getPoints());
    item2.setRequired(item1MC.isRequired());

//  the choices
    var choices = item1MC.getChoices();
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        item2.createChoice(choices[i].getValue(),choices[i].isCorrectAnswer());
    }
    item2.setChoices(choices);
//  the feedback
    var feedback1 = item1MC.getFeedbackForCorrect();
    item2.setFeedbackForCorrect(feedback1);
    var feedback1 = item1MC.getFeedbackForIncorrect();
    item2.setFeedbackForIncorrect(feedback1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully cleared about your question, but If you want an easy way to do a relationship between Google Sheets (columns) and Google Forms Drop-down lists and other Forms objects, you can try this add-on: formRange. Build your sheets then go to your Form and Addons. Chose formRange and install it. It's pretty easy to use and you have a little tutorial inside it.

[formRanger: Google Form addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formranger/faepkjkcpnnghgdhiobglpppbfdnaehc?utm_source=permalink)